# Call a segue from another Navigation Controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I'm trying to jump to a View that's on another Navigation Controller. 
You Can see the situation from my storyboard:
[image]

Once I get to the the "*Edit Sticker*" view i want to go back to the "*Create Pack*" but I don't want that the "back" that I get once i click **save** takes me back to "*Edit Sticker*", it should take me to the view that's on the left of "*Create pack*".
You can see the situation from this:
[image]

What could be a good solution?
How can I invoke a segue (the first one you see on the first picture on the top left, that's calling "*Create pack"*) that's on another Navigation view controller?

**UPDATE:**
Tried setting it with one Navigation Controller:
[image]

and programmatically setting this when I press *Add*:

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
```

takes me back to the "*1st View*". I need to go the "*Create pack*" view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How come the `Edit Sticker` view controller is on its on navigation controller?

If the navigation hierarchy went `Root` -> `Create Sticker` -> `Edit Sticker`, you can call `self.navigationController.popToRootViewController` when the user clicks save.

But if you want to control the segue, then use `self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(animated: Bool)` as that just pops the view on top to give you more control.

Comment: thank you for the reply but it doesn't work. I updated the Question for more details on the problem. Because it's Root -> 1st view -> create sticker -> edit sticker

Comment: Ahh, I assumed that 1st view was the root view. Try calling `self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(false)` twice to pop off the `Edit Sticker` then the `Create Sticker`. If you want the segue to be animated then change the bool to `true`

Comment: Sorry, I read the update wrong. If you just want to go back to the `Create Sticker` view after pressing save, then just `popViewControllerAnimated` once.

Comment:  thank you! it works. If you update the answer I can accept it.